# How does a serial queue/private dispatch queue know when a task is complete?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

(Perhaps answered by [How does a serial dispatch queue guarantee resource protection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19010732/1449799) but I don't understand how)

**Question**

How does gcd know when an asynchronous task (e.g. network task) is finished? Should I be using `dispatch_retain` and `dispatch_release` for this purpose? **Update:** I cannot call either of these methods with ARC... What do?

**Details**

I am interacting with a 3rd party library that does a lot of network access. I have created a wrapper via a small class that basically offers all the methods i need from the 3rd party class, but wraps the calls in `dispatch_async(serialQueue) { () -> Void in` (where `serialQueue` is a member of my wrapper class).

I am trying to ensure that each call to the underlying library finishes before the next begins (somehow that's not already implemented in the library).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The serialisation of work on a serial dispatch queue is at the unit of work that is directly submitted to the queue.  Once execution reaches the end of the submitted closure (or it returns) then the next unit of work on the queue can be executed.

Importantly, any other asynchronous tasks that may have been started by the closure may still be running (or may not have even started running yet), but they are not considered.

For example, for the following code:

```
dispatch_async(serialQueue) {
    print("Start")
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue) {
       functionThatTakes10Seconds()
       print("10 seconds later")
    }
    print("Done 1st")
}

dispatch_async(serialQueue) {
    print("Start")
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue) {
       functionThatTakes10Seconds()
       print("10 seconds later")
    }
    print("Done 2nd")
}
```

The output would be something like:

> Start
>
> Done 1st
>
> Start
>
> Done 2nd
>
> 10 seconds later
>
> 10 seconds later

Note that the first 10 second task hasn't completed before the second serial task is dispatched.  Now, compare:

```
dispatch_async(serialQueue) {
    print("Start")
    dispatch_sync(backgroundQueue) {
       functionThatTakes10Seconds()
       print("10 seconds later")
    }
    print("Done 1st")
}

dispatch_async(serialQueue) {
    print("Start")
    dispatch_sync(backgroundQueue) {
       functionThatTakes10Seconds()
       print("10 seconds later")
    }
    print("Done 2nd")
}
```

The output would be something like:

> Start
>
> 10 seconds later
>
> Done 1st
>
> Start
>
> 10 seconds later
>
> Done 2nd

Note that this time because the 10 second task was dispatched *synchronously* the serial queue was blocked and the second task didn't start until the first had completed.

In your case, there is a very good chance that the operations you are wrapping are going to dispatch asynchronous tasks themselves (since that is the nature of network operations), so a serial dispatch queue on its own is not enough.

You can use a `DispatchGroup` to block your serial dispatch queue.

```
dispatch_async(serialQueue) {
    let dg = dispatch_group_create()
    dispatch_group_enter(dg)
    print("Start")
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue) {
       functionThatTakes10Seconds()
       print("10 seconds later")
       dispatch_group_leave(dg)
    }
    dispatch_group_wait(dg)
    print("Done")
}
```

This will output

> Start
>
> 10 seconds later
>
> Done

The `dg.wait()` blocks the serial queue until the number of `dg.leave` calls matches the number of `dg.enter` calls. If you use this technique then you need to be careful to ensure that all possible completion paths for your wrapped operation call `dg.leave`.  There are also variations on `dg.wait()` that take a timeout parameter.

Comment: this is FAN-TASTIC! question: if DispatchGroup is an unresolved identifier, does that mean I'm on Swift 2? 1? (I know i'm not on 3) Should I probably use dispatch_group_create, dispatch_group_enter, and dispatch_group_leave as in (e.g.) http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/ ?

Comment: That's right; I default to Swift 3 :)  I should probably clean up my answer, since at the moment it is a mixture of 2 and 3.

Comment: do you think the dispatch_group_wait is necessary? like if I were going to have 2 of the blocks like you have at the very end of your answer, wouldn't the dispatch_group_enter and dispatch_group_leave calls implement serialization already? (and the output then be the same as that from your second block?)

Comment: Nope, `dispatch_group_enter` doesn't block; you can call it as many times as you like. It just keeps increasing rhendispstch_group "count". `dispatch_group_leave` decreases that count and `dispatch_group_wait` blocks until the count is 0. You can also use `dispatch_group_notify` to submit a block to be executed when're count becomes 0. This is used when you want to execute some code when a number of asynchronous tasks that may be running in parallel have completed.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before, `DispatchGroup` is a very good mechanism for that.

You can use it for synchronous tasks:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
DispatchQueue.global().async(group: group) {
   syncTask()
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    // done
}
```

It is better to use `notify` than `wait`, as `wait` does block the current thread, so it is safe on non-main threads.

You can also use it to perform async tasks:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()
asyncTask {
   group.leave()
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    // done
}
```

Or you can even perform any number of parallel tasks of any synchronicity:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

group.enter()
asyncTask1 {
   group.leave()
}

group.enter() //other way of doing a task with synchronous API
DispatchQueue.global().async {
   syncTask1()
   group.leave()
}

group.enter()
asyncTask2 {
   group.leave()
}

DispatchQueue.global().async(group: group) {
   syncTask2()
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    // runs when all tasks are done
}
```

It is important to note a few things.

1. Always check if your asynchronous functions call the completion callback, sometimes third party libraries forget about that, or cases when your `self` is `weak` and nobody bothered to check if the body got evaluated when `self` is `nil`. If you don't check it then you can potentially hang and never get the notify callback.
2. Remember to perform all the needed `group.enter()` and `group.async(group: group)` calls before you call the `group.notify`. Otherwise you can get a race condition, and the `group.notify` block can fire, before you actually finish your tasks.

> BAD EXAMPLE

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

DispatchQueue.global().async {
   group.enter()
   syncTask1()
   group.leave()
}

group.notify(queue: .main) { 
    // Can run before syncTask1 completes - DON'T DO THIS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question in your questions body:

> I am trying to ensure that each call to the underlying library finishes before the next begins

A serial queue *does* guarantee that the tasks are progressed in the order you add them to the queue.

---

I do not really understand the question in the title though:

> *How* does a serial queue ... *know* when a task is complete?